# Jpackage check if mysql 8 is installed, if not install it

Tags: javafx, java-11, mysql-8.0, jlink, jpackage

is there any possibility to implement MySQL 8 installation in my java project, which is packaged with jpackage, so when the user clicks on the .exe installation (made by jpackage), it simply checks if mysql8 has already been installed, if not it also installs it .

Comment: I don't believe so. But if there is then it should be documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A

Comment: thank you, unfortunately, they didn't mention such an option, i really want to send the project to the user in the forme of one .exe file, so they won't need to go and  install MySQL 8 by themselves

Comment: There are other, lighter-weight, highly functional databases you could use instead of MySQL. You could bundle an embedded dbms with your application distribution, then you wouldn't need to have the user install anything else.  I would *highly recommend an embedded database over the approach you are taking*.  I recommend using the [H2 database](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) stored [to a file](https://www.baeldung.com/h2-embedded-db-data-storage).  Optionally, you could also use [springboot-jpa](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database).